# Maven repackage transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

The app consists of modules and each module is particular maven project with one parent. These modules are used as jars in main app. 
Each module uses third party SDK via maven.
These SDKs have many dependencies and these dependencies can be with the same group and artifact but with different versions. It is hard to manage them and we have problems with 'NoSuchMethodError's. As for me the simplest way to fix problem is to get sources of problematic dependencies and source of SDK, change the package (add some prefix) and imports and put it inside sdk jar.
But this approach requires: one more git repository for forked SDK's jars and private maven repository to publish them and a lot of time.
Is there maven plugin that can help with this problem, for example plugin that can build jar (our module jar) with all dependencies included inside it but can change package of all dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Maven shade plugin which allows you to relocate classes

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

but I have never tried this myself.

In most cases it is better to try to align the dependencies so that you use the same versions in most places and also to reduce dependencies to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you are confronted with a classpath problem called "jar hell". The only safely working solution i know is the use of different classloaders for each version of the same class (if it's not backward compatible).

A class is identified by its qualified name (package and class name) and by the classloader it has been loaded. If the application uses the default system classloader and there is the same class in different versions in the classpath only one version will be loaded by the classloader. In the oracle JDK/JRE it is the one which occurred first in the classpath. If you are lucky you can bring the classpath (order and excluding dependencies) in a special order in which your application will run, but i wouldn't recommend it since it relies heavy on the JDK/JRE implementation.

OSGI is a technology which might be helpful for this since it provides a module based framework for using different classloaders.